# How can I output and array inside column JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to save JSON in CSV file, but when I run the code, I get this result:

[image]

How can I output this key and values in separated columns using python?

Here is what I have so far:

```
vendas_pandas = pd.json_normalize(request,
                                    meta= ['cartao'])

if vendas_pandas.empty:
    print("---DataFrame Vazia---")
           
vendas_pandas.drop(
    vendas_pandas.columns.difference(
        ['controle','numCartao','qtdCliente','horAbertura','horFechamento','valTaxaServico']),
        1,
        inplace=True
        )
```

With this code, the return CSV file is a file without columns.

Comment: Please edit your question to include screenshot in body of question with Ctrl+V instead of a link.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of general text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)